# Merge multiple files and convert in to single PDF using .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

In my application, option is there to upload multiple attachments, that can be png, jpg, doc or .xlsx and its working fine using .Net MVC.

Now I want to merge all these attachments into a single PDF. Is that possible using .net MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use: [pdfsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/).

PDFsharp is a .NET library for processing PDF file. You create PDF pages using drawing routines known from GDI+. Almost anything that can be done with GDI+ will also work with PDFsharp. Only basic text layout is supported by PDFsharp, and page breaks are not created automatically. The same drawing routines can be used for screen, PDF, or meta files